# EV-SSL root CA autoinstalls on browser without confirmation

Tags: ssl, ca

While browsing https://www.quovadisglobal.ch/Repository/DownloadRootsAndCRL.aspx site I noticed right after that when I browsed my trusted CA certificates it had automatically downloaded the trusted root CA without asking for my confirmation.

To reproduce the isue just perform the following steps:
- Ensure you have no QuaVadis trusted root CA.
- Open the site https://www.quovadisglobal.ch/Repository/DownloadRootsAndCRL.aspx.
- Close the browser
- Open again browser and check root CA certificate.

You will find the QuoVadis trusted root CA that was installed without asking for confirmation from the user.

I tried this with both IE8 and FF.